# AppDynamics: : Can I run monitors in round robin mode?

Tags: appdynamics

Does AppDynamics provide similar functionality ?

I was checking out [ThousandEyes doc](https://docs.thousandeyes.com/product-documentation/browser-synthetics/using-round-robin-test-scheduling#round-robin-mode) where I can run monitors in round robin mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following contexts your query does not make sense (as reporting is based on usage of the instrumented application):

1. Application Agents
2. Machine Agents
3. Database Agents
4. Analytics Agents
5. MRUM Agents
6. BRUM Agents

For Synthetics (which are scheduled by the user) - there is indeed the option to use Round-Robin when configuring a Job - please see screenshot:
[image]